# Registering .onion with Certificate Authority?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, onion-services, server

Is it possible to register my onion with LetsEncrypt? I'm using Arch.

If no, why not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

Currently only [EV certs that are valid for both some canonicle domain and an onion address](https://blog.digicert.com/anonymous-facebook-via-tor/) are able to have TLS certificates issued but not an onion address alone, and not non-EV certificates.

This is essentially a policy thing internal to the CA/Browser forum.

From [Ryan Sleevi's response to Alec Muffett asking the same question](https://cabforum.org/pipermail/public/2015-November/006213.html):

> "- At Google, we were (and are) concerned with the cryptographic strength of
>   the .onion naming scheme, which employs both SHA-1 and RSA-1024."
>
> "- Related to that first point, the choice of EV discourages attackers
>   making such cryptographic attacks against sites operating .onion sites, as
>   it requires some form of identity validation of who the attacker is, even
>   if they have the cryptographic resources to mount such an attack."
>
> "- While this is a position that we (Google) generally disagree with, many
>   CAs feel that it should be their responsibility to police subscriber's
>   content and revoke certificates whose content they (or their governments)
>   disagree with."

Further reading: "[onion address support](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/91)", "[Letsencrypt for .onion?](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/letsencrypt-for-onion/10045/5)"

Comment: fortunately, this is no longer accurate.

Comment: Onion services can now register SSL certificates for Onion services.

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2020, [this is now technically possible](https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder/issues/4620#issuecomment-589197404), but it has yet to be implemented by Let's Encrypt.

#### Why https for `.onion` domains?

First, I think it's necessary to point out that there are non-security-related, logistical reasons for why you'd want to add a valid TLS cert for a website served on an onion service: there are many [tools/protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) that are designed to [stubbornly refuse to work over http](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/letsencrypt-for-onion/10045/23).

Even though a service is securely hosted through a `.onion` on http, it may not be possible to get existing services working over an onion service domain without using https and a valid cert.

Moreover, it can be non-trivial to point a `.onion` at existing websites without serving them over https, and [just getting a cert for your `.onion` sites may be the easiest way to bring your existing websites up on the tor network](https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder/issues/4620#issuecomment-735219149).

#### Ballot SC27v3: Version 3 Onion Certificates

In early 2020, a proposal ([Ballot SC27v3: Version 3 Onion Certificates](https://cabforum.org/2020/02/20/ballot-sc27v3-version-3-onion-certificates/)) was presented to the [CA/Browser Forum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA/Browser_Forum), requesting CAs to be able to issue EV & OV certificates for v3 `.onion` domains. It passed unanimously in February 2020.

#### ETA for Let's Encrypt?

At the time of writing, Let's Encrypt's ACME protocol does not support issuing certificates for the `.onion` domain, but there is a ticket open to add this feature.

- https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder/issues/4620

The ticket linked-above specifically mentions that they aren't sure if there's enough demand for this feature to warrant allocating resources to implement issuing certs for `.onion` domains. So, if this is important to you, then I recommend adding a +1 to the ticket linked above ;)

...And maybe add a comment on why this is important to you if you have another use-case that hasn't yet been considered.

#### Non-free CAs

You can view a list of all the Onion Services with https certificates here:

- https://crt.sh/?q=%25.onion

Notable Certificate Authorities that sell certificates with support for .onion sites include:

1. [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/blog/ordering-a-onion-certificate-from-digicert/)
2. Hellenic Academic and Research Institutions CA
3. Commercié Extended Validation Server CA

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2021, it appears the [HARICA](https://www.harica.gr/Products/ServerCertificate), a certificate authority based in Greece, also allows you to obtain an SSL certificate for a .onion domain. While HARICA offers them cheaper,

To quote their website, one of the types of certificates they offer is listed as

> **SSL DV Onion** (Domain Validated - Onion): SSL/TLS Server Certificate that includes one or more RFC 7686 ".onion" special-use Domain Names (e.g. [www.4gmrlefxkq4mtan6a2lqwfwa7un4brjlatka75nwdczemqqwn3wznnad.onion](http://www.4gmrlefxkq4mtan6a2lqwfwa7un4brjlatka75nwdczemqqwn3wznnad.onion), mysite.4gmrlefxkq4mtan6a2lqwfwa7un4brjlatka75nwdczemqqwn3wznnad.onion)

I would still buy a certificate from DigiCert if you need to prove your organization's ownership of an onion site as HARICA does not appear to offer EV certificates for .onion sites.

Note: I would have added this answer as a comment to @Michael Altfield's great answer above, but I do not have sufficient reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's an open question: is it good that you can't have a SSL certificate for your onion? The truth is that the organizations selling you them now are regulated and can be enforced to shut them down, so - IMHO - only a decentralized CA can do the job *properly*. Try looking at EmerSSL - it's an Emercoin built-in technology that can do this in a correct way: you're issuing your certificate and publishing it's public data in a decentralized manner, so no one can shut it down